# remove duplicates in a char array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have array of pointers in  liste_tmp with values "123" , "456" , "123"

Declaration :

```
char  *no_rlt_liste[5] , *liste_tmp[5]; int i, j, count =0;
for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
    for ( j= 0 ; j< count; j++){
            if (liste_tmp[i] == no_rlt_liste[j]){
                    break;
            }
            if (j == count){
                    no_rlt_liste[count]  = liste_tmp[i];
                    printf(" ENTER\n");
                    count++;
            }
    }
}
for (i = 0 ; i < count; i++)
    printf("Final result %s\n", no_rlt_liste[i]);
```

the above code doesn't produce result. not able to identify the bug. 
any help?
Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)? And I assume you clipped out the code where you actually properly initialize `liste_tmp[]` and `no_rlt_liste[]` ?

Comment: What is `n` in `for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++)`?

Comment: You will probably need to use `strcmp()` to compare strings, probably in place of `if (liste_tmp[i] == no_rlt_liste[j])`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loops never run because of the condition `j< count`, and you have set `count =0`.

Comment: While presumptive on my part, I've a suspicion the code posted has *all* of the initialization (the arrays, count, etc) omitted. Still, this seems correct, so +1, though I still think the comparison is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize `count` to `0` which cause the inner for loop to not execute (since `j < 0` is always `false`), thus your whole loop doing nothing.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
{
  int flag = 0;
  for (j= 0; j< count; j++)
  {
    if (liste_tmp[i] == no_rlt_liste[j])
    {
      flag = 1
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!flag)
  {
      no_rlt_liste[count]  = liste_tmp[i];
      printf(" ENTER\n");
      count++;
  }
}
```

Also, be aware that you need to use `strcmp` if you do not want to compare the char-pointers, but their contents instead:

```
   if (strcmp(liste_tmp[i], no_rlt_liste[j]) == 0)
   {
      flag = 1
      break;
   }
```